# Browse all links in a zone with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a CSS rectangle in which they are links.

```
+-----------------------+
|  <a href="test">      |
|      <a href="toto">  |      
|<a href="link3">       |
+-----------------------+
```

I want to browse all  tags in this rectangle and get all their href attributes.

How can I do to browse all element in this rectangle ?

**The rectangle and  tags have an absolute position** ( tags doesn't inherits from rectangle class), so I think we have to browse with coordinates ? Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I make a possible solution :

- Get the position of the rectangle
- Get all icons of the document

`spe_rect.find('.my-icon').mousedown(function(e){
            var x_min = spe_rect.offset().left;
            var x_max = spe_rect.offset().left + spe_rect.width();
            var y_min = spe_rect.offset().top;
            var y_max = spe_rect.offset().top + spe_rect.height();
            console.log('X Min : ' + x_min + ' ' + 'X Max : ' + x_max);
            console.log('Y Min : ' + y_min + ' ' + 'Y Max : ' + y_max);

            $('#doc a.icon').each(function(i, element){
                if ($(element).offset().left > x_min &&
                    $(element).offset().left < x_max &&
                    $(element).offset().top > y_min &&
                    $(element).offset().top < y_max){
                    console.log($(element).attr('href'));
                }
            });
        });`

Comment: While this may work, it will be slow and painful, and you really shouldn't have to do it this way at all if the page is built in a way that is sane.

Comment: I think I can't do it in other way... It's not so much slow while there are maximum 20 elements (<a> tags) in the entire page and while the functionality is not often used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you rectangle has a class, you would do.

```
$('.rectangleClass a').each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element.href);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the rectangle has an absolute position (<a> tags too) so the links doesnt inherit from the rectangle class. Have you other way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: So according to the DOM, the `<a>` tags are not children of the rectangle?  Is that what you are saying?  If so that is very bad design, because it makes things like this very very hard.